# Is it possible to make mods in C++ for the bedrock edition on a Windows 10 PC?

Tags: c++, minecraft

(thread title) bedrock minecraft more recognizable as "Windows 10 Edition" Minecraft, is it possible to create a sub category UI menu similar to that in Java minecraft where it says "mods" but in bedrock? and to add mods you make a mods folder that adds the mods coded in C++ (which the language bedrock/windows 10 MC is coded in)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

although this has been answered by @Kosaro, I just wanna add that you can create plugins to use on a [PocketMine](https://www.pocketmine.net/) server. this is mainly written in YAML and PHP, so its not really what your looking for exactly but it a bit more open than just the addons that Minecraft allows you to create. plugins like this are what make things like slapping a NPC on a server like Mineplex possible, or an economy system on a factions server. although this is all dependent on whether you have a pc to host the server, and if your willing to port forward to play with others

Answer (score 2):

No, Minecraft Bedrock edition (aka Windows 10 edition) does not support C++ mods. The only type of mod that Bedrock edition supports are "add-ons", which are either resource packs (which change textures, models, sounds, animations, etc) or behavior packs (which change how mobs behave).

You are able to modify the UI using resource packs, here is an example from the official wiki: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Bedrock_Edition_creator_guidelines#UI

You can find more information and tutorials on the official reference page: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Add-on

Comment: i see okay thanks for the answer! i was going to learn C++ but i knew i better get an answer before i spend a year wasting my time learning a language that doesnt actually fulfill something i want to make lol

Answer (score 2):

It is possible through Blocklauncher. And these mods are called native Mods. It involves disassembling a file in Minecraft apk and using the function calls to call our own function. It is actually so complex. I only found two places to learn.

- [Tutorials by artus9033](http://artus9033.blogspot.com) (I've never used these Tutorials)
- [Github page by byteandahalf](https://github.com/byteandahalf/MCPE-NativeMods/wiki) (**Note:** Page 9 is WIP)

Blocklauncher also uses javascript as a bridge between C++ and Minecraft, but it only has very few functionalities compared to C++. Add-ons are also good but have very fewer functionalities than javascript.

Hopes it helps you

**Edit1:** Blocklauncher is dead I don't know it before. It will work for older versions.

**Edit2:** There is another app inspired by Blocklauncher which you may like
https://github.com/TripleCamera. I don't know how to install it, but he made it. Blocklauncher scripts will not work (I guess). Blocklauncher works for version 12 and below of Minecraft

Comment: Hey wait. Blocklauncher is dead. I never knew it before. It won't work for recent versions

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible but it would be very involved and I’m not sure if this would be what the question really pertains to. The way I’ve seen it done is by a program (modding client) injecting itself into the Minecraft process. The injection resembles a virus’s methodology somewhat and the source code for the hacking/modding program was mostly cpp. Look up horion hacked client github. The client seems to be dead now though.